# Realtime Content and Database Replication for Alfresco

Tags: postgresql, real-time, replication, alfresco

I'm currently researching on how to replicate physical files (store contents) and the meta data (database) of Alfresco. This is of course a safety measure in case of server failure or whatsoever.

Currently i am running Alfresco's Database on PostgreSQL Engine, and by far, have learned PostgreSQL's WAL and Stream replication. Of which i believe, i can use in terms on replicating Alfresco's meta data (database) real time.

The next problem i face now, is as to how i can replicate alfresco's repository/physical files (store contents) in real time ?

i am currently looking at Alfresco's Built-in Replication Job. But as far as i have read, it is "scheduled" and not in real time. And, it needs another instance of Alfresco running on the "SLAVE" Server.

So my question is:

Does Alfresco's Built-in Replication Job cover both the Physical/Repository Files (store contents) and meta data (database) contents ?

or

what is/are the viable ways of replication Alfresco's Physical/Repository Files (store contents) and meta data (database) contents in real time ?

Comment: hoping Mr Potts can view this post again and give me tips

Comment: The easiest solution is probably just to ring your Alfresco account manager, upgrade your subscription to Clustering, and turn the built-in Alfresco clustering support on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replication service can be used to replicate objects from one Alfresco server to another at the object level, not the file system and database level. So, of course there are files and database records that are created when an object is replicated, but the those are by-products of the object being created in the replication target.

The replication service is really used to make it easier for objects in a particular path to be read by people in another office. When they read the object they get it locally. When they click "Edit" in Share they will be redirected back to the source Alfresco server.

Long story short, the replication service is in no way, shape, or form, to be used to replicate data for backup or disaster recovery.

If you are running on EC2 or a local filer that supports it, it should be enough to take volume snapshots.

Otherwise, you could use something like rsync scheduled with cron.

But this approach sounds risky. I'm not sure how you will ensure that your database is kept in sync with your file system, which is a requirement for your Alfresco repo to remain consistent.

Comment: i've mistook Alfresco's Replication Service as a DRM Measure. Anyhow, i've done quite a long research. Apparently, i won't be able to use Rsync as i am running on a Windows Server 2012 Machine. Nonetheless, i've bumped accross this `Syncrify` in which i synchronize `alf_data` to the backup server. i've also ran several tests to make sure if it works. the backup server has a cold alfresco instance (not running) installed, i simulated a main server failure and imported the synced `alf_data` to the cold alfresco instance then ran it. and it surprisingly worked. this altogether with the db files.

Comment: thank you for the idea Mr Potts. While this approach really is risky given the integrity of the Repository Files and the Database Files, it would still be counted as a better than nothing kind of approach.